# VSCode Latex Workshop Snippet View

Tags: ide

In a recent update to VSCode's Latex Workshop extension, a "Snippet View" was added. I'm not sure if something is wrong on my end or in general or maybe I'm not understanding something, but it appears incomplete to me.

Below are some images of how it appears to me. Seems like pictures are missing?
Also the "symbols", "TikZ", and drop down button don't do anything.

Has anyone else had better luck, or understand better than me what is supposed to be going on here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using VS Code Remote, it is a bug of VS Code. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/112641

Comment: Hm - would using VSCode on WSL count as "remote"?